# C++ template class explicit instantiation failing with GCC/NDK

Tags: android, c++, templates, gcc, android-ndk

I have a template class in a header .hpp file:

**Rage.hpp:**

```
//various includes...

template<typename... Args>
class Rage : public PlatformManagerDelegate
{
    bool paused;

    //other variables...

public:
    Rage(Args... args);
    void pushInitialState(std::unique_ptr<State> state);

    //other methods...
};
```

and it's implementation in a source .cpp file, with explicit instances at the end of the file:

**Rage.cpp**:

```
#include "Rage.hpp"
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
//other includes...

template<typename... Args>
Rage<Args...>::Rage(Args... args) : paused(false)
{
    //some code...
}

template<typename... Args>
void Rage<Args...>::pushInitialState(std::unique_ptr<State> state)
{
    //some more code...
}

//more methods...

template class Rage<>;
template class Rage<struct android_app*>;
```

Compiling the following in main.cpp

```
#include "Rage.hpp"
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>

void android_main(struct android_app* appState)
{
    app_dummy();

    Rage<>* clientInstance = new Rage<>();
    clientInstance->beginRun();
}
```

gives:

```
undefined reference to 'Rage<>::beginRun()'
undefined reference to 'Rage<>::Rage()'
```

This code compiles perfectly fine using MSVC from Visual Studio 2013 (obviously changing android_main to the standard main function), so any help on what I seem to be doing wrong to get it compile on GCC/NDK would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you linking the code?

Comment: I haven't changed anything to do with linking so not sure tbh, should I post my Android.mk and Application.mk? Everything else seems to link fine (internal to project and external stuff).

Comment: No. Just the link line.

Comment: How would I get this? Should I do ndk-build V=1 ?

Comment: I have no idea - I'm not an Android developer. However, given that this question didn't trigger any other reaction I'm trying to help from the basic C++ perspective and from that it looks as if the file with the instantiations isn't included in the build (well, that's covering the constructor; the member `beginRun()` is also not defined but I assume that it was just cut when copying the code).

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I stripped out all template code and it still isn't linking correctly (I' tried this earlier but must have made a mistake). Also yep I should have included the definition of beginRun() in the question. Silly me! When I confirm this, if you post it as an answer then I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Android developer so I can't reproduce the problem. From a basic C++ perspective it looks as if the file with the instantiations isn't included in the build. Well, that's covering the missing constructor instantiation. The member `beginRun()` is not defined at all but I assume that it was just cut when copying the code and is actually defined in `Rage.cpp`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I had `FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../source/*.cpp)`
`FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../source/android/*.cpp)`
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)` instead of the second FILE_LIST using += so only my platform specific code was being built (which includes main.cpp), and at the same time was templating my Rage class so instantly assumed it was that. Thanks!